# Lambda calculus operator precedence and reduction strategies

Tags: lambda, calculus, reduction

**1.**
In lambda calculus applications have higher precedences than abstractions. Now in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7702/applicative-order-and-normal-order-in-lambda-calculus) example the author shows two reductions in normal and applicative order. The first is:

```
(λx.x^2 (λx.(x+1) 2))) → (λx.x^2 (2+1)) → (λx.x^2 (3)) → 3^2 → 9
```

My problem lies within the 1st and 3rd step. Why can he reduce like this

```
(λx.x^2 (3)) → 3^2
```

if application has a higher precedence than abstraction? Shouldn't this be true:

```
λx.x^2 (3) = λx.(x^2 (3))
```

and therefore no reduction should be possible? The way he interprets the term is

```
λx.x^2 (3) = (λx.x^2) (3)
```

which is incorrect.

**2.**

Afaik these are the definitions of 4 reduction strategies.

```
Normal Order:       Leftmost outermost redex reduced first
Applicative Order:  Leftmost innermost redex reduced first
Call by value:      Only outermost redex reduced                Reduction only if right-hand side has been reduced to a value (= variable or abstraction)
Call by name:       Leftmost outermost redex reduced first      No reductions inside abstractions
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168678/call-by-value-in-the-lambda-calculus) innermost and outermost only refers to abstractions. Does leftmost (and rightmost) similarly only refer to applications?

**3.**

So is this a correct recursive algorithm for applicative order reduction (in pseudo code)?

```
evaluate(t : Term) {
    if (t is Abstraction) {
        evaluate(t.inside)
    } else if (t is Application) {
        evaluate(t.first)
        if (t.first is Abstraction) {
            t.first.apply(t.second)
        }
    } else if (t is Variable) {
        do nothing
    }
}
```

Abstraction, Application and Variable are all child-classes of Term. The function "apply" applies the given term to the abstraction. The data structures look something like this (please ignore the missing pointer syntax):

```
class Abstraction {
    var : Variable
    inside : Term
}
class Variable {
    name : String
}
class Application {
    first : Term
    second : Term
}
```

**4.**
In the link in **1.** the author gives an example on a term that can be reduced to normal form with normal order but not with applicative order, because in the latter case the reduction will not terminate. Is there a term where the reduction terminates but yields different results with both strategies? If so, what would be an example?

Sorry for the long question, I didn't want to create 4 different threads for this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You're actually asking four questions. Split them up into four questions (separate question posts) so that they can be answered independently.

Comment: It will only let me post a question every 90 minutes...